# How to find capital letter using RegExp?

Tags: regex

I need a simple solution. I have a text that is improperly punctuated and in many places a comma is followed by a capital letter. Example: *Here you are, You sicko.* A comma followed by a cap. Any string to find these? ,\w doesn't work. I only want caps.

I only know basic regex. I'll use it to search in Notepad++

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
, [A-Z]
```

In general case, for any punctuation,

```
[.,!?\\-]+ [A-Z]+
```

See image below: 
[image]

Link: https://regex101.com/r/BrGZmF/1

Comment: Nope. Still finding lower case chars too.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Any idea why it isn't working in Notepad++?

Comment: And if you can help me to exclude a character, like I as it is supposed to be cap.

Comment: you have to check "Match case" in the find

Comment: I have added a screenshot

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: you can accept the answer to avoid other's from trying to answer it